# Encapsulate Hangfire Creation Methods with Fire and Forget APIs

Tags: hangfire

Till the Hangfire supports async/await, is it a good idea to encapsulate the call of the jobs creations methods within fire and forget APIs such as [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn636892%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) ?

examples:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((cancelationToken) => BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SomeClass.DoWork()));
```

or

```
BackgroundTaskManager.Run(() =>
{
  BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SomeClass.DoWork());
});
```

Comment: Async is already here http://hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html

Comment: no, this is about supporting the async/await within the job code, hangfire still didn't support pushing the jobs to the jobs database using async/await, i.e there is no overload like: BackgroundJob.EnqueueAsync

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. When you call `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` method, the current thread will move to the next statement while your `SomeClass.DoWork` method will be executed later by a Hangfire thread. What else do you need?

Comment: the current thread will not be moved to next statement until the job and its parameters are saved to the job database (this is not related to the execution of the job itself), so it will be blocked, if there are Async overloads of the jobs creation methods (like suggested EnqueueAsync) and a real support for the asynchronous data access layer, that will enhance the overall performance of the web client application because then there will be no blocked threads and then can be used to serve other requests

Comment: So you need this for performance issues as you have identified the enqueuing as taking too long? I'd be curious to know what performance gap you would gain from this since I have not noticed any issue on that side. Have you run benchmarks on this?

Comment: yes, I am trying to enhance the overall performance, the hangfire performance actually doing very good, but the issue I am pointing to is about blocking the threads not the time needed to call the enqueue function, if you have no blocked threads waiting for I/O operations like here saving  the job to database, then IIS can use these threads to receive more requests which then will enhance the capacity and performance of the web application